# Inner join two querysets

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlite, django-rest-framework

I have three models
**Learner**, **Level** and the through model **LearnerLevel**.

The models look like this:

```
class Learner(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    words = models.ManyToManyField('Word', through='LearnerWord', related_name='Learners')
    levels = models.ManyToManyField('Level', through='LearnerLevel', related_name='Learners')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
class Level(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    selectedByUser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    words = models.ManyToManyField('Word', through='LevelWord', related_name='levels')
    countWords = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    language = models.ForeignKey('Language', related_name='languagelevels', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,
                                 blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class LearnerLevel(models.Model):
    learner = models.ForeignKey('Learner', related_name='learnerlevels', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    level = models.ForeignKey('Level', related_name='learnerlevels', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    knownWords = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.learner.user.username + ' ' + self.level.name
```

The tables look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM app_level;

id|name          |countWords|language_id|selectedByUser
1 |A1            |0         |1          |0
2 |A1 Supermarkt |0         |1          |0
3 |A1            |22        |2          |0
4 |A1 Albanisch1 |20        |4          |0
5 |A1 Albanisch2 |17        |4          |0
6 |A1 Albanisch3 |21        |4          |0
7 |A1 Albanisch4 |20        |4          |0
8 |A1 Albanisch4 |20        |4          |0
9 |A1 Albanisch5 |20        |           |0
10|A1 Albanisch7 |20        |4          |0
11|A1 Albanisch8 |20        |4          |0
12|A1 Albanisch9 |20        |4          |0
13|A1 Albanisch10|20        |4          |0
14|A1 Albanisch11|20        |4          |0
15|A1 Albanisch12|20        |4          |0

SELECT * FROM wordapp_learnerlevel;

id|knownWords|learner_id|level_id
1 |8         |1         |4
2 |16        |1         |5
3 |3         |1         |6
4 |8         |1         |1
5 |8         |2         |4
```

My first question is, how can I achieve the following with Django?

```
SELECT wordapp_level.name, 
       wordapp_level.countWords, 
       wordapp_learnerlevel.knownWords 
FROM   wordapp_level 
INNER JOIN wordapp_learnerlevel 
       ON wordapp_level.id = wordapp_learnerlevel.level_id;

name         |countWords|knownWords
A1 Albanisch1|20        |8
A1 Albanisch2|17        |16
A1 Albanisch3|21        |3
A1           |0         |8
A1 Albanisch1|20        |8
```

My goal is to get a new queryset that I can give to a modelview in the get_queryset function from the django-rest-framework.
My second question is, is that good practice?

I want something like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    learnerStatistic = LearnerLevel.objects.select_related('level')
    return learnerStatistic
```

So for example the learner has learned from level with the id 1 2 3. Now in learnerlevel the knownWords changed where the level_id is 1 2 3. Now I want to give the user a statistic. "You learned **learnerlevel.knownWords** of **level.countWords** from **level.name**"

It is not clear to me from the Django documentation

========== EDIT ==========

I tried

```
str(LearnerLevel.objects.select_related('level').query)
```

I get

```
SELECT "wordapp_learnerlevel"."id", "wordapp_learnerlevel"."learner_id", "wordapp_learnerlevel"."level_id", "wordapp_learnerlevel"."knownWords", "wordapp_level"."id", "wordapp_level"."name", "wordapp_level"."selectedByUser", "wordapp_level"."countWords", "wordapp_level"."language_id" FROM "wordapp_learnerlevel" LEFT OUTER JOIN "wordapp_level" ON ("wordapp_learnerlevel"."level_id" = "wordapp_level"."id")'
```

but when

str(LearnerLevel.objects.select_related('level').values().query)

I get

```
SELECT "wordapp_learnerlevel"."id", "wordapp_learnerlevel"."learner_id", "wordapp_learnerlevel"."level_id", "wordapp_learnerlevel"."knownWords" FROM "wordapp_learnerlevel"
```

but I just want **learnerlevel.knownWords**, **level.countWords**, **level.name**

If I do

```
qs = LearnerLevel.objects.select_related('level').only('knownWords','level__name','level__countWords')
```

then

```
qs.values()
```

is

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'learner_id': 1, 'level_id': 4, 'knownWords': 8}, {'id': 2, 'learner_id': 1, 'level_id': 5, 'knownWords': 16}, {'id': 3, 'learner_id': 1, 'level_id': 6, 'knownWords': 3}, {'id': 4, 'learner_id': 1, 'level_id': 1, 'knownWords': 8}, {'id': 5, 'learner_id': 2, 'level_id': 4, 'knownWords': 8}]>
```

But I expect it to be

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'name': 'A1', 'knownWords': 8, 'countWords': xx}, .....]>
```

====== Solution ======

I found the solution

```
def get_queryset(self):
    currLearner = Learner.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
    return currLearner.learnerlevels.values('knownWords', 'level__name', 'level__countWords')
```

and the serializer is

```
class LearnerLevelXXSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    knownWords = serializers.IntegerField()
    level__name = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    level__countWords = serializers.IntegerField()
```

Thank you Denis Cornehl. Your advice helped me

Answer (score 1):

About the first question: 
You can achieve the result exactly with the queryset seen. Since the relation is 1:n (there can be multiple `LearnerLevel` for one `Level`) you start at `LearnerLevel`, and `select_related` the `Level` object.

One thing that always helped me getting from pure SQL to the Django ORM: 
use the `.query` and convert to string, then you will see the sql query django generates (sql formatting added):

```py
./manage.py shell
>>> from wordapp.models import Level, LearnerLevel
>>> qs = LearnerLevel.objects.select_related('level')
>>> str(qs.query)
'SELECT 
"wordapp_learnerlevel"."id", 
"wordapp_learnerlevel"."learner_id", 
"wordapp_learnerlevel"."level_id", 
"wordapp_learnerlevel"."knownWords", 
"wordapp_level"."id", 
"wordapp_level"."name", 
"wordapp_level"."selectedByUser", 
"wordapp_level"."countWords" 
FROM "wordapp_learnerlevel" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "wordapp_level" ON (
    "wordapp_learnerlevel"."level_id" = "wordapp_level"."id"
)'
>>>
```

Now you could of course reduce the result columns (by using `.values()`, `.only()` or similar), in general especially when you use other django-libraries (like django-rest-framework) it's easier to directly work with the model instances until you have to optimize for performance.

About the second question: 
It can be good practice. Typically for REST-APIs you try to think in resources and list of resources (DRF added *list/detail actions* on top). In my mind your example fits resources, since you are returning the levels for all the users languages.

Hope I could help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited my post. When I use LearnerLevel.objects.select_related('level').values(learnerlevel.knownWords, level.countWords, level.name) I get an error.

Comment: @tag try defining the fields you want not on .only but as parameter to .values